# Is it possible to link one MDB to another in a standalone manner?

Tags: ms-access, linked-tables

Is it possible to link one MDB to another in a standalone manner?

Ie. If I have the accounts table in `db1.mdb` and the products table in `db2.mdb`, can both these MDBs be coded so that they can link to each of the tables in a seamless manner?

Comment: @Craig Have you proven your VB app does not crash when the MDB contains only a small subset of the data?

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish here? Accounts and Products belong in the same MDB file, especially if they are related (indeed, you can't set up engine-level referential integrity except for tables in the same MDB).

Comment: @David: I'm just using it as an example. I want to take a very large table out of one MDB and put it another in order to avoid problems associated with larger MDB files.

Comment: @HansUp: No but Error 3343 is being reported: "Unrecognised database format 'xyz.mdb', which I think means the database is unreadable because either someone has broken it by trying to open it in a newer version of Access, or it is too big. I am preparing for the possibilily that it is too big.

Comment: If your tables are too large for MDBs, then you've outgrown Jet/ACE and should switch to a database engine with larger capacity.

Comment: @David: That is not an option in the short term because it would involve significant redevelopment of the front end app.

Comment: If I were in your position, I'd start trying to get the parts in motion to move towards whatever is needed to move to a different back end. And I'd strongly urge that you design the app to not be so tightly tied to one particular database so you don't run into this problem should you discover issues with the new database engine, too.

Comment: I agree that different backend would be a good idea. What do you think of Firebird?  However, this plan would something that would take several years.  I need to handle the scenario of large MDB files for the short-term.

Comment: My impression of Firebird is that it may very well be great, but it's very thinly used. I have fond feelings about Borland and all its orphaned children, but don't think I'd recommend it. I'm not sure it's a server back end (though I believe that, like Jet/ACE, can function as an intermediary layer to other db engines), in any event, and wouldn't recommend any file-based solution as a replacement for Jet/ACE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just do it. You can create linked tables in MS Access, and the Jet engine does not care anymore in which MDB file the data resides.

In fact it is good practice to separate the data db from the code db, because you can send updated code dbs without the need to update the data db to your customers.

Btw. we stopped storing data in MDBs altogether, because they tend to break regulary. Better start using the Microsoft Desktop Database Engine immediatly, and just place the code in thr MDB.

Comment: I have been working with mdbs for a number of years and they do not "break regularly" unless they are very badly set-up.

Comment: I have worked with MDBs for about 6 years now, and they broke regulary. I have to admit, that the 20 users using the one backend concurrently on a remote windows host might have been too much. We switched to a real server based database now.

Comment: Access databases are prone to breakage when used across an unreliable network. In 5 years experience I encountered one which broke (corrupted) on two occasions.  That one was a database opened directly from a network share by more than one user at a time.  It never broke again after we split it and gave each user their own local copy of the front-end with links to the data in the networked back-end database.

Comment: @Daniel: the key part of your statement is "on a remote windows host." You can't use Jet/ACE except on a wired LAN with reasonable bandwidth. This is to be expected of a file-based database engine.

Comment: To second @Remou and @HansUp, I don't see "breakage" of MDBs/ACCDBs, and I've been at this since 1996. Sure, the occasional hiccup occurs, but only very, very seldom. Regular maintenance and proper backups insure no loss of data or any downtime for users.

Comment: What is "Microsoft Desktop Database Engine"? I've never heard of the term. Do you mean SQL Server Express?

Comment: @David: what do you mean by 'regular maintenance'?  Do you mean compacting?  If so, how often should it be done?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: Access has shooten me in the foot more than one time. Maybe I use it in the wrong way, but I am glad to have switched to Java, where I can debug everything down to the lowest level because I have the source of everything.

Comment: @Craig Johnston: if you were running a SQL Server you'd have regular maintenance routines scheduled, and a Jet/ACE database should be no different. How often to compact depends on the amount of updating/adding that is being done to your database. Once a month or once a week will suffice for some database, while once a day is better for others. Never do a compact without a backup, but your database should be backed up daily, not just when you compact it.

Comment: @Daniel: I can't see how Java is a replacement for Access, so don't know why if what you want to do can be done in Jave you'd have ever been attempting to use Access. The discussion here is not even regarding Access as development platform, but Jet/ACE (Access's default db engine), so your comments seem completely off the wall to me.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: Yes, that comment really is of the wall. I just felt the urge to say that MS Access is definitely so broken for what I tried to to with it, and I really can say for me that I have done a ton of development with it, that I now feel better not having to do it more, that for maintenaining what we have.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: Hell, I even wrote a Subversion plugin for Access, to be able to have a chance of a definite state in which I work on, with four other programmers working on that beast also.

Comment: @Daniel: why you need to badmouth Access as development tool is beyond me. You seem to have irrational emotional problems in regard to Access. I don't think those are Access's fault.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: I cannot completely disagree. Sorry for continuing this useless discussion. Althought it is IMHO at least partly Access's fault ...